# Using Riemann Sums to calculate area of an irregular shape

Tags: geometry, riemann-sum

sorry I'm really new to this and this is literally my first question on this website.

So I have this question:
"Imagine that you have a patch of grass of an irregular shape growing in your backyard. You wish to know its approximate area in square feet. How might you approach this?"

So my idea to a solution would be to put this shape onto the Cartesian plane and then taking the Riemann sum, so that it would be the Riemann sum of the "top" of the patch subtract the Riemann sum of the "bottom" of the patch (if the shape is concave). However, how would I describe this scenario if the shape is convex? I know what it should look like and it's pretty intuitive for me, but how would I be able to describe it?

Is there a better/more efficient way to solve this question?

Thanks!

Comment: You can simplify/generalize the problem by simply taking rectangles over the shape. No need to deal with the "top, bottom" business.

Comment: A better method entirely might be to break up the plot into triangles and solve for each using Heron's formula. You can use Delaunay triangulation if the choice of triangles are difficult to choose.

Comment: So really just splitting the area into a ton of rectangles/triangles is one of the best ways to approach the problem? Ok got it. Thank you so much!